# Multiple bugs, no reason

Tags: java

This program is designed in the end to make a slot machine like thing that will be integrated into a friend's game, still in pre alpha stages and will be for a long time or maybe forever. (he's only using it for a class project ATM)

```
package SlotMachine;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;

public class SlotGui{


        static Random one = new Random();
        static Random two = new Random();
        static Random three = new Random();
        static Random four = new Random();
        static Random five = new Random();
        static Random six = new Random();
        static Random seven = new Random();
        static Random eight = new Random();
        static Random nine = new Random();
        static int st = one.nextInt(10);
        static int nd = two.nextInt(10);
        static int trd = three.nextInt(10);
        static int frth = four.nextInt(10);
        static int fth = five.nextInt(10);
        static int sxth = six.nextInt(10);
        static int svth = seven.nextInt(10);
        static int eth = eight.nextInt(10);
        static int nth = nine.nextInt(10);
        static int coins = 15;
        static JTextField money = new JTextField(Integer.toString(coins));
        static JLabel blueLabel = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotOne = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotTwo = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotThree = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotFour = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotFive = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotSix = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotSeven = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotEight = new JLabel();
        static JLabel slotNine = new JLabel();
        static Icon lever = new ImageIcon("lever.jpg");
        static Icon a = new ImageIcon("0.jpg");
        static Icon b = new ImageIcon("1.jpg");
        static Icon c = new ImageIcon("2.jpg");
        static Icon d = new ImageIcon("3.jpg");
        static Icon ee = new ImageIcon("4.jpg");
        static Icon f = new ImageIcon("5.jpg");
        static Icon g = new ImageIcon("6.jpg");
        static Icon h = new ImageIcon("7.jpg");
        static Icon i = new ImageIcon("8.jpg");
        static Icon j = new ImageIcon("9.jpg");
        static JButton startLever = new JButton(lever);
        static Color backGround = new Color (0,0,0);

        public static void slotVisualSet(JLabel slot,int Xval, int Yval, int h, int w){
            slot.setOpaque(true);
            slot.setLocation(Xval,Yval);
            slot.setSize(h,w);
            slot.setVisible(true);  
        }

            public static void slotLogic(JLabel slotLab,int slotNum){

                if (slotNum == 0){
                        slotLab.setIcon(a);
                    } else if (slotNum == 1){
                        slotLab.setIcon(b);
                    } else if (slotNum == 2){
                        slotLab.setIcon(c);
                    } else if (slotNum == 3){
                        slotLab.setIcon(d);
                    } else if (slotNum == 4){
                        slotLab.setIcon(ee);
                    } else if (slotNum == 5){
                        slotLab.setIcon(f);
                    } else if (slotNum == 6){
                        slotLab.setIcon(g);
                    } else if (slotNum == 7){
                        slotLab.setIcon(h);
                    } else if (slotNum == 8){
                        slotLab.setIcon(i);
                    } else if (slotNum == 9){
                        slotLab.setIcon(j);
                    }
            }

            public static void makeWindow(){

            //creating the window

                JFrame windo = new JFrame ();
            windo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            windo.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                windo.setVisible(true);

                //creating the components of the window


                    money.setOpaque(true);
                    money.setLocation(500,900);
                    money.setSize(60,20);

                    blueLabel.setOpaque(true);
                    blueLabel.setBackground(backGround);
                    blueLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
                    blueLabel.setVisible(true);
                    blueLabel.setLayout(null);                      
                    //setting the coordinates and sizes of the slots
                    slotVisualSet(slotOne,100,100,225,225);
                    slotVisualSet(slotTwo,350,100,225,225);         
                    slotVisualSet(slotThree,600,100,225,225);
                    slotVisualSet(slotFour,100,350,225,225);
                    slotVisualSet(slotFive,350,350,225,225);
                    slotVisualSet(slotSix,600,350,225,225);         
                    slotVisualSet(slotSeven,100,600,225,225);
                    slotVisualSet(slotEight,350,600,225,225);
                    slotVisualSet(slotNine,600,600,225,225);


                startLever.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int st = one.nextInt(10);
                    int nd = two.nextInt(10);
                    int trd = three.nextInt(10);                
                    int frth = four.nextInt(10);
                    int fth = five.nextInt(10);
                    int sxth = six.nextInt(10);
                    int svth = seven.nextInt(10);
                    int eth = eight.nextInt(10);
                    int nth = nine.nextInt(10);
                    coins = coins - 5;
                    money.setText(Integer.toString(coins));
                    // making the slots change pictures when the lever is pulled
                    slotLogic(slotOne,st);
                    slotLogic(slotTwo,nd);
                    slotLogic(slotThree,trd);
                    slotLogic(slotFour,frth);
                    slotLogic(slotFive,fth);
                    slotLogic(slotSix,sxth);
                    slotLogic(slotSeven,svth);
                    slotLogic(slotEight,eth);
                    slotLogic(slotNine,nth);

                    if ((st == nd) && (nd == trd)){
                        coins = coins + 30;
                    }else if((frth == fth) && (fth == sxth)){
                        coins = coins + 30;
                    }else if ((svth == eth) && (eth == nth)){
                        coins = coins + 30;
                    } else if ((st == fth) && (fth == nth)){
                        coins = coins + 100;
                    }else if ((svth == fth) && (fth == trd)){
                        coins = coins + 100;
                    }

                }
            }); 
            startLever.setSize(183,275);
            startLever.setLocation(1000,300);


                windo.add(startLever);
                windo.add(money);
                windo.add(blueLabel);
                windo.add(slotOne);
                windo.add(slotTwo);
                windo.add(slotThree);
                windo.add(slotFour);
                windo.add(slotFive);
                windo.add(slotSix);
                windo.add(slotSeven);
                windo.add(slotEight);
                windo.add(slotNine);

            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                makeWindow();

            }
        } );
    }   

}
```

There are three bugs here, I have been looking for answers forever and have not been able to find any, so help would be much appreciated.

1. The ninth slot does not go listen to the placement parameters for some reason and just sits on the side.
2. The slots do not always appear after you click the button that is supposed to change the images (maybe I need to use something other than JLabels for this?)
3. The background doesn't change colour.

Comment: If possible, I would recommend using arrays. This code is hard to follow.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a debugger.

Comment: Have you tried the code step-by-step under debugger to see what **exactly** is going on?

Comment: Correct title should be "Multiple bugs, at least one reason" as in you wrote your program incorrectly.

Comment: You **should not** be using multiple `Random` instances. You should typically use only one [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) for entire application! Since they are all instantiated at the same time, it's very likely that they will all produce the same sequence of numbers. Again, use only one `Random`.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but...
The reason that i use more than one random is because it would generate one number and only be good for one slot, there are nine slots

Comment: @ROBBYNATOS you can generate as many numbers as you want with a random number generator. Just call `nextInt()` lots of times and you'll get different numbers each time.

Comment: ^

@ PM77-1

I still havent learned to use a debugger. (im such a noob XP)

Answer (score 5):

There are so many issues with that code that are problematic, let me enumerate some:

- Trying to set location of a component on a non-null layout using container
- Trying to use set location at all and not use layout managers. That's what they're there for, to make it easy to create complex GUI's without fussing with exact positioning.
- Not using arrays.
- Over use of static. None of the fields should be static. **Edit:** except for the background color which could very well be a constant, a static final variable named BACKGROUND.
- Using nine Random objects. One would work just fine and would be a lot less confusing.
- .... etc...
- posting code for a "friend's" class project.

---

I think that the best fix-up for this code is to trash it, and instead try to re-write the code from scratch using arrays, using layout managers, avoiding static variables. Start over and you could create a nice GUI and quickly too, and learn quite a bit in the process.

---

**Edit 2**

- Consider using a GridLayout using JPanel to hold your 3 x 3 grid of JLabels.
- Consider using a BorderLayout for your overall GUI, placing the GridLayout JPanel into the BorderLayout.CENTER position.
- The play button could go in a JPanel that is placed in the main GUI BorderLayout.EAST position.
- The bet window could go in a JPanel that is located in the main GUI in the BorderLayout.SOUTH position.
- Again use of arrays will simplify and shrink your code, making it much easier to debug and to enhance.
- The same goes for use of layout managers as they will make it easier for you to debug, enhance and modify your GUI.

Comment: - It's not my "friends code" it is my code for my friend
- could you explain how to do this without overuse of static please
- I like the precise positioning and Don't mind writing the extra code, besides that's not an error just a coding preference
- Oh and thanks for pointing out that the container isn't set to a null layout

Comment: @ROBBYNATOS for your friend's class project?

Comment: yea, it started as a class project but he wanted to expand on it and i had this code lying around that i could fix up and implement

Comment: `"besides that's not an error just a coding preference"` perhaps, but there is good code, and there is bade code. Too much code is bad code.

Comment: @ROBBYNATOS: the best fix-up for this code is to trash it, and instead try to re-write the code from scratch using arrays, using layout managers, avoiding static variables. Start over and you could create a nice GUI and quickly too, and learn quite a bit in the process.

Comment: @ hovercraft full of eels ok I think that would be a good idea

Comment: @ROBBYNATOS: see **Edit 2** above.

Comment: @ hovercraft full of eels thanks for being the only one who gave me some suggestions rather than pointing out what had already been said